# Quota script for a roster

Tags: google-apps-script, rostering, rosters

I'm trying to make a script that reads a specific column(B), checking each cell for "is this value < 120?".

If the value is < 120, I want the script to add a value of "1" to the corresponding cell in a different column(E).

This is what I've come up with so far, but it's not working and I can't figure out why.

```
function quota1() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Roster");


  var workingCell = sheet.getRange("B:B").getValue();

  if(workingCell < 120){
    sheet.getrange("E:E").add(1);

  }

}
```

[Picture of roster for better understanding.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5uKF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If col2 less 120 increment column 5 by 1

```
function quota1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Roster");
  const vs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),5).getValues();//get all data
  let vo = vs.map((r,i) =>{
    if(r[1] < 120) {
      return [r[4] + 1];//add one
    } else {
      return [r[4]];//no change
    }
  });
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vo));//easier see the column
  sh.getRange(1,5,vo.length,vo[0].length).setValues(vo)
}
```

Before:

|  | 105 |  |  | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 106 |  |  | 6 |
|  | 107 |  |  | 7 |
|  | 108 |  |  | 8 |
|  | 109 |  |  | 9 |
|  | 110 |  |  | 10 |
|  | 111 |  |  | 11 |
|  | 112 |  |  | 12 |
|  | 113 |  |  | 13 |
|  | 114 |  |  | 14 |
|  | 115 |  |  | 15 |
|  | 116 |  |  | 16 |
|  | 117 |  |  | 17 |
|  | 118 |  |  | 18 |
|  | 119 |  |  | 19 |
|  | 120 |  |  | 20 |
|  | 121 |  |  | 21 |
|  | 122 |  |  | 22 |
|  | 123 |  |  | 23 |
|  | 124 |  |  | 24 |

After:

|  | 105 |  |  | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 106 |  |  | 7 |
|  | 107 |  |  | 8 |
|  | 108 |  |  | 9 |
|  | 109 |  |  | 10 |
|  | 110 |  |  | 11 |
|  | 111 |  |  | 12 |
|  | 112 |  |  | 13 |
|  | 113 |  |  | 14 |
|  | 114 |  |  | 15 |
|  | 115 |  |  | 16 |
|  | 116 |  |  | 17 |
|  | 117 |  |  | 18 |
|  | 118 |  |  | 19 |
|  | 119 |  |  | 20 |
|  | 120 |  |  | 20 |
|  | 121 |  |  | 21 |
|  | 122 |  |  | 22 |
|  | 123 |  |  | 23 |
|  | 124 |  |  | 24 |